# Can't migrate link_to after adding Bootstrap button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, slim-lang

This td link works with Slim. After this paste, I'll show what doesn't work.

```
td=(link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
                        method: :delete,
                        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' })
```

I've added Bootstrap buttons to these links.

```
td 
  a class="btn btn-info" href=(article_path(article)) Show
```

This is my attempt at replacing the link with a button.

```
td
   a class="btn-danger" href=(article_path(article),
                                        method: :delete,
                                        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }) Destroy
```

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong or fix the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting on a `link_to` block:

```
td
  = link_to article_path(article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => 'btn btn-danger' do
    span
      | Destroy
```

Comment: That worked! I started converting all my erb files to slim and then added Bootstrap. Sweet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about try with working code (I dony):

```
td=link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

> BTW `href` of `<a>` only accepts path or url, not another `<a>`, as `link_to` produces a `<a>`

Cheers!

Comment: I edited the broken one that still doesn't work. I forgot to remove the link_to.